# I wanna know the meaning of 'lonely me'

Tags: meaning, lyrics

In the lyrics of the song by Big Bang. The great k pop boy band.
"loser, lonely me, faking tough, and cowardly."
I wanna know the meaning of lonely me and faking tough.
please tell me. I wanna sing this song in English.
Is there any verb form of fake?

Comment: These aren't special phrases and mean what the words say literally.

Answer (score 1):

"Lonely me" is a way of stating your loneliness. It is often said as a lament, along the lines of "poor you". There is nothing unusual about the phrase at all, but I can see how an English learner would find it unusual - we wouldn't say "Lonely I".

That's just the difference between the personal pronouns 'I' and 'me' - the former is used as the *subject* and the latter is used as the *object*.

"Lonely me" says more than "I am lonely". It suggests that the adjective describes the person, that they are perhaps *perpetually* lonely, whereas "I am lonely" could just be a statement of your current feelings.

---

"Faking tough" means that someone is pretending to be tough (physically or mentally strong).

"Tough" is normally an adjective - you would say someone *is* tough. A more verbose way of saying this would be "faking *being* tough". However, an adjective can sometimes be a noun representing the *state* or *quality* of that it describes. The actual noun would be '*toughness*', so you could also say "faking toughness", but "faking tough" works just as well.